# NetworkStream.Write vs. Socket.Send

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I have a c# application that I use a custom FTP library for. Right now Im using Socket.Send to send the data but I was wondering if it would be better to initiate a NetworkStream with the socket and use NetworkStream.Write instead.

Are there any advantages to using one over the other?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The advantage of a `NetworkStream` derives primarily from the fact that it is a `Stream`.  The disadvantage of a `Socket` is that common code that reads and writes from abstract I/O sources like a `Stream` cannot handle a `Socket`.

The main use case for a `NetworkStream` is that you have some code elsewhere that reads or writes from a `Stream`, and you wish you could use it with a `Socket`.  You would know if were in this situation and then `NetworkStream` would be a big help!

Say for example you had a communications library and you supported serializing messages from files, named pipes and TCP/IP.  The ideal choice for the I/O class would be `Stream`.  Then your serialization methods could accept a `FileStream`, a `PipeStream`, or a `NetworkStream`.  It would even accept a `MemoryStream`.  This is the benefit of **abstraction** because after we've **created** the stream, a method can **interact** with it without knowing what kind of stream it is.

In this sense, a `NetworkStream` uses the **adapter** design pattern.  It adapts the `Socket` API to the `Stream` API so that clients that are expecting a `Stream` can use it.

So finally, the question, if `NetworkStream` is a `Stream` adapter for a `Socket`, which one should we use?  Well, if you **need** a `Stream`, then `NetworkStream` is your only choice.  If you don't need a `Stream`, then you can use whichever API you are most comfortable with.  If you are already using `Socket` successfully, there is no pressing reason to switch to `NetworkStream`.

Comment: Can I just add to this that NetworkStream also has much better async support

Comment: @LukeMcGregor That isn't true. `NetworkStream` does not implement Task-based async support directly, instead it relies on `Stream`'s own APM-to-Task functionality which isn't as ideal as "native" Task-based async (it uses `TaskFactory.FromAsync`). Furthermore, the `BeginRead`/`BeginWrite` (APM) methods simply wrap `Socket.BeginReceive`/`Socket.BeginSend` which aren't as high-performance as the (confusingly named, non-Task-based) `Socket.SendAsync` and `Socket.ReceiveAsync` methods.

Comment: further, neither TPL nor APM async models are "high-performance" compared to "native" IOCP and overlapped I/O, but this is a sockets programming concept beyond most developers these days and a lost art for most people claiming to be "Windows programmers."  IOCP also remains platform specific technology, but will send/receive data faster than any "user mode" solution invented in the depths of the BCL.  If you want "the fastest tx/rx performance possible under windows" you want raw sockets, static buffers, and IOCP w/Overlapped I/O (or an equivalent native solution on a non-Windows platform.)

Answer (score 3):

You can potentially separate creation of `NetworkStream` and to work with that as with abstract `Stream` - so you'll be able to change your transport or simply to create `Stream` stubs for testing.

As a  question of method itself - `NetworkStream.Write` inside has the only operation (except state checks)  `streamSocket.Send(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None);` - so it's mostly the same as to call that on socket.

Answer (score 3):

One disadvantage of using the **.NET Framework** implementation of `NetworkStream::Write` is that if the underlying network ([OSI layers 1-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) is unable to receive the entire data buffer you are not made aware (except, perhaps, by inspecting .NET Networking performance counters.)

#### Unreliable.

Something like this appears in `NetworkStream::Write` of Microsoft's .NET Framework **System.dll**:

```
try
{
    socket.Send(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None);
}
/* ... catch{throw;} */
```

Note how the return value, which represents the count of bytes written by `Send()`, is discarded. This suggests `NetworkStream::Write` is unreliable for sub-par networks (roaming/wireless), or networks that may become IO bound (exceeding available bandwidth.)

#### More than one implementation.

You can find other implementations which write all bytes until all of `buffer` has been written (or other failure occurs.) It is a standard method of sending data, and will always exhibit the following behavior:

```
var count = 0;
while (count < size)
{
    count += socket.Send(buffer, offset + count, size - count, ...);
}
```

#### What does this mean?

You can write proper and reliable send() code by calling `Socket::Send` directly, you cannot write proper and reliable send() code calling `NetworkStream::Write`.

As an aside, other variations of `NetworkStream` do not have the same problem the BCL disassembly shows (see [mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs),[cosi2](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/50866950/)), and still others show similar problems despite their best efforts (see [flourinefx](https://code.google.com/p/fluorinefx/source/browse/trunk/Source/FluorineFxSL/Util/NetworkStream.cs?r=159)).

#### References

1. [Mono Repository on Github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs)
2. [FlourineFxSL Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/fluorinefx/source/browse/trunk/Source/FluorineFxSL/Util/NetworkStream.cs?r=159)
3. [cosi2 Repository on BitBucket](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/50866950/) (via searchcode.com)

Comment: According to the documentation for `socket.Send`: "In nonblocking mode, Send may complete successfully even if it sends less than the number of bytes you request. It is your application's responsibility to keep track of the number of bytes sent and to retry the operation until the application sends the requested number of bytes." - so this bug does not apply in cases that don't use nonblocking sockets, and nonblocking is the default, so most users should be okay.

Comment: Also, `NetworkStream`'s constructor will throw an `IOException` if a nonblocking `Socket` (`if( !socket.IsBlocking ) {` instance is passed in to its constructor.

Comment: i upvoted your comment because it was accurate, not because i agreed with your interpretation of the problem. _it IS possible to use a non-blocking socket despite the ctor check._ i have personally dealt with this problem in the past and it is worth people understanding that it is there. this COULD be fixed within netfx by adding a loop around the Socket::Send call as is done in other implementations (corefx, mono, others) but "the docs say" continues to be the defense for allowing this bug to exist in the first place.