# Deserializing data from a network stream hangs using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, sockets, json.net

Data received through a socket using `JsonSerializer`:

```
var stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, new UTF8Encoding(), false))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var result = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader).ToString();                
}
```

But the call to the `Deserialize` hangs when the length of data received from the socket is about 2890 bytes.

It can be easily reproduced by using this code (when `jsonArrayElementsCount = 192` - ok, when `193` - it hangs):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonNetHangsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int port = 11999;
            const int jsonArrayElementsCount = 193;

            var serverStartedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var clientReceivedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

#region server
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(work =>
            {
                var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), port);
                server.Start();

                serverStartedEvent.Set();

                var serverSocket = server.AcceptSocket();

                var jsonString = "[\r\n" + String.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("  \"testdata\"\r\n", jsonArrayElementsCount)) + "]";
                var bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(jsonString);
                serverSocket.Send(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("server send: " + bytes.Length);

                clientReceivedEvent.WaitOne();

            });
#endregion

            serverStartedEvent.WaitOne();

            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", port);

            var stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, new UTF8Encoding(), false))
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var result = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("client receive: " + new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(result).Length);
            }

            clientReceivedEvent.Set();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the tail end of the JSON you are sending is getting buffered on the server side.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> There is also no guarantee that the data you send will appear on the network immediately. To increase network efficiency, the underlying system may delay transmission until a significant amount of outgoing data is collected. A successful completion of the Send method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send.

Thus you need to ensure the socket buffer gets flushed.  However, there's no `Flush()` method on [`Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  So, what to do?

1. The easiest thing to do is to dispose the socket as soon as you are done with it:

   ```
           int byteCount;
           using (var serverSocket = server.AcceptSocket())
           {
               byteCount = serverSocket.Send(bytes);
           }
           Console.WriteLine("server send: " + byteCount);
   ```

   (Disposing of disposables as soon as you are done with them is a good idea always.)
2. Alternatively, wrap the `serverSocket` in a `NetworkStream` that owns the socket, then dispose of the stream (which amounts to the same thing):

   ```
           var serverSocket = server.AcceptSocket();
           using (var ns = new NetworkStream(serverSocket, true))
           {
               ns.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           }
   ```

   (But see [NetworkStream.Write vs. Socket.Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555011/networkstream-write-vs-socket-send/32596327#32596327) which suggests it's sometimes necessary to check the value returned from `serverSocket.Send(bytes)`.)

You might want to consider handling [`SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Here's one suggestion for how to do it: [C# Examples: Socket Send and Receive [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/).

Comment: And on the client side there is no problem? (in production I've no access to the server side). One more strange thing: with Json.NET 4.5 sample code works as expected (originally I used 7.0 version of Json.NET). And one more: `stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytes.Length)` on the client side works perfectly (without hangs) - seems problem is in Json.NET library.

Comment: I used Wireshark on my production server to analyze TCP packets - and packets are the same in case of hanging and normal working. It depends on the run. It also seems the problem is in library or some client socket settings?

Comment: @DenisGnatyuk - [`JsonTextReader.ReadData(bool append, int charsRequired)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) reads until the underlying `stream.Read()` returns zero bytes, and then assumes the file is closed.  This *seems* to be the right thing to do for sockets, since they [don't have an explicit disconnect event](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fa70bde-d967-44a8-911c-7c9160d37447/disconnect-event-needed?forum=netfxnetcom).

Comment: @DenisGnatyuk - I was able to reproduce your problem with your excellent MCVE -- and verified that disposing the socked fixed the problem.  Are you still seeing the problem in client/server communications after the fix?

Comment: As you have mentioned, `JsonTextReader.ReadData` waits until stream returns zero bytes, but in my case server doesn't close the socket after sending response, because clien-server communication based on request/response within one session (socket connection). That's why I can't use your fix.

Comment: @DenisGnatyuk - If the server won't close the socket, you may need to look into [Message Framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).  Or if you're saying the client just needs to send a response to the server, maybe see [How To Signal End Of Data Without Closing NetworkStream in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535901).

Comment: But the strange thing is that `JsonTextReader.ReadData` sometimes hangs and sometimes works perfect. It depends on json data.

Comment: IMHO Message Framing is great when we use 'TLV like' protocol, but in case of text protocol based on JSON - I can't imagine why it's a problem to serialize and deserialize packets through socket. I had experience with the same JSON protocol over sockets - and node.js works well with it.